# Openssl implementation of improved sha1 hashing

Tags: hash, sha-1

I want to use the improved sha1 hashing algorithm from the Intel blog described [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/improving-the-performance-of-the-secure-hash-algorithm-1/#comment-72104) Intel sha1 hashing. Currently I am using Openssl sha1 hashing in my application.

1. I wanted to know if anybody has used the Intel sha1 hashing and how does it compare against Openssl implementation as far as performance is concerned?
2. Also the source code provided there is in assembly and just defines 'update' function. What do I need to use it in place of Openssl sha1, which provides functions like 'init', 'final'? I can't use the Openssl implementation of these functions because they use some Openssl specific things.
3. Where can I find Openssl implementation of improved sha1 hashing based on 64 bit instruction set. It is an alternative implementation of this. I tried to find it in my /usr/inclusde and /usr/lib/ but could not get it. It seems it is an add-on to Openssl (openssl-addons/intel-accel/) but does not come with Openssl package. Also how to use it in place of Openssl's usual sha1?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography Stack Exchange. Your question is about a specific implementation of SHA-a on a specific platform, and as thus not really on-topic here (we are more on the theoretic side). As you already [asked on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9887536/600500), I'm closing the question here. I would recommend expanding the question there similar to the one here.